# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on wp get_footer

Tags: php, wordpress, php-parse-error

I started building a template and...

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="box-posts">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  </div>
  </div>
<?php

  get_footer();

?>
```

(This was index.php, okay, it's simple.

```
  <div id="footer">
  <br />
  Copyright (C) 
  <br /><br />
  </div>
  </center>
  </body>
  </html>
```

(And this was footer.php)
I really can't see anything wrong here, but i get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end"

Comment: -1 from my end because this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. I will also vote to delete it after it got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot the `endwhile;` and `endif;` statements. The [alternative PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) requires a specific `xend;` statement.

Quoting from the manual:

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

In particular:

```
if ():
    ...
endif;
```

and

```
while ():
    ...
endwhile;
```

Comment: Oh, that's true. So sorry, that was a really dummy question. Thanks about the fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

You must add add terminating statements for `if` & `while` - That is `endif` for `if` & `endwhile` for `while`.

Hope this Helps !!

Answer (score -2):

use this to close `endif` and `ifs`

```
    <?php get_header();?>
     <div id="box-posts">
       <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
       <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
       <?php else: ?>
       <p>sorry no results</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
  </div>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: True, but not the cause of the parsing error.

Comment: @Polygnome Its one of the error. So why dowvote

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but this is not the answer to the question "why am I getting this parse error".

Comment: @Polygnome and Jeffrey is this fine now

Comment: No, it's wrong. Only cause I have a <div> unclosed on header. But thanks anyway.

Comment: The oroginal answer only related to a closing </div>, which is NOT the cause of the parse error, hence the downvote.